# Varistor-based SPD device - how does it protect the load?

Tags: varistor

These common SPD devices are put in the main panel of residences: https://aptghana.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/SPD-2.jpg.

This basic circuit showcases how they are installed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIvQcX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They are put in parallel with the source and the installation, but somehow they are able to stabilize the the voltage seen by the installation in the cause of a transient source voltage peak.

I researched a lot and, in all sources that I have read, it is mentioned that the working principle is that: when the varistor experiences a big voltage peak in its terminals, its "resistance" is lowered, causing a (almost) "short circuit". This "short circuit" ensures that the varistor will receive a large current, which results in the installation being protected (?)

What I don't understand is: How exactly the fact that the resistance of the varistor is dropped has any effect on the voltage seen by the installation?

The varistor is in parallel with the installation, so, theoretically, even if we replaced the varistor by a 0.000001 ohm resistor, the installation would still see the same voltage. The only difference would be that the resistor would receive a giant current, without any impact on the installation.

In my mind, the only explanation that I can think of is: the parasitic resistance of the source/line is taken into consideration. When the resistance of the varistor is lowered, it is expected that it will become so low that it will be comparable with the parasitic resistances of the source/line, thus causing a voltage divider and, therefore, causing part of the voltage to be "absorbed" by the parasitic resistance of the source. In this scenario, the voltage experienced by the installation would indeed be reduced. However, I was not able to find this explanation anywhere, and relying on the parasitic resistences of the source/line seems weird to me.

Could anyone clarify it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, mains is not an ideal source.  There are two dominant components: resistance and inductance.  A typical residential circuit might have an impedance of 50mΩ or thereabouts, which can be mostly resistance, or inductance, but probably a mixture of both applies.

Consider a long wired circuit: a standard US 120V 60Hz 15A circuit uses 14 AWG wire, and if it's 50 ft. from the panel, the run adds 250mΩ, and maybe 5-10 µH of stray inductance.

Inductance depends modestly on wire length alone, but compounds particularly when wound up into a coil.  Most likely, significant inductance arises when a circuit passes through one or more transformers.  50mΩ reactance at 60Hz is 130µH, a typical leakage inductance for a 1kVA control transformer (commonly used in industrial equipment, where 120V is desirable for control circuitry, while the main supply is 240-480V).

If we take 100µH as a typical source inductance, then if we consider a 50µs surge of say 2kV peak, the flux under the curve is of the order (2kV)(50µs) = 100mWb, and the change in current, (100mWb)/(100µH) = 1kA.

Indeed, a typical combined-wave generator, used for testing surge immunity under regulations such as IEC 61000-4-5, emits a 8/20µs (that's a 10-90% risetime of 8µs, and a FWHM of 20µs) pulse into a near-short-circuit load, and a 1.2/50µs pulse into a near-open-circuit load (the time varies with load impedance, thus, "combined" wave).  The effective impedance of this generator, the ratio between open-circuit peak voltage and short-circuit peak current, is apparently 2 ohms -- conveniently, we also found 2kV and 1kA peak based on rough assumptions, how about that?

As it happens, the CWG equivalent circuit uses typical values on the order of 8 µF, 3 µH and 2Ω, so we expect significant attenuation in a real circuit when values exceed these amounts.  Such capacitors might be typical of passive power factor correction (capacitors balancing the inductive load of motors and transformers on site), stray wiring (again, adding up some 10s µH is easy enough across a building), and internal resistance of the equipment (small power supplies, with common-mode chokes of several ohms resistance, can use smaller MOVs, or potentially none at all).

As such, actual effects may vary.  Perhaps the EUT (equipment under test) is near another SPD already.  In that case, the Thevenin source impedance can be much smaller: less wiring distance between means less resistance and stray inductance, and the clamping impedance of the SPD itself is quite low during the pulse.  But the pulse is a lower amplitude, maybe 800V, instead of the unlimited 1.5kV entering the system (say from distant induced lightning strike).

Induced or direct lightning strike itself, is handled by the mains distribution network, with SPDs installed periodically along distribution lines.  Above-ground SPDs are easy to spot: the insulators are colored and shaped differently, and there is a noticeable ground wire/rod connected to the insulators' mounting bracket.  These reduce the surge on e.g. 4.8kV AC lines to a peak of maybe 20kV, as measured some 100s of m away from the strike.  (Closer to the strike, direct EMP is far stronger, and if you're in that zone... expect destruction regardless; EMC standards consider direct hits rare enough to not include them in commercial testing.)  Eventually, the circuit routes to a distribution transformer ("pole pig" or pad type), some filtering occurs, rounding off the peak (transformers are also filter networks of a sort), and if the polarities work out, saturation may clip the pulse shorter as well.  Most surge is therefore reduced under a kV by the time it reaches a customer, with worst-case figures in the low kV.  2.5kV line-to-ground and 1.5kV line-to-line are typical test levels.

Comment: Thank you very much for your brilliant response! There is still a detail that is making me confused. My understanding is that the purpose of the varistor is to try to estabilize the voltage of the load/installation. However, given that the impedance of the source/line is usually small, it looks to me that, in order for the varistor to achieve that, it will need to draw a lot of current. Therefore, it will inevitably activate the circuit breaker. Does this make sense?

Comment: For example, for a 127V AC source with 2ohm impedance. A peak that elevates it to 254V will require that the varistor reduces it "resistance" to 2ohms (roughly), such that the voltage is equally divided between the varistor and the line. However this will make the varistor draw more than 50A, which is already enough to activate some residential circuit breakers. For 1000V peak, it is even worse

Comment: Varistors aren't very resistive, and I think it's kind of a historical accident that they've been described that way, but it also doesn't mean much as you can have a device with voltage as a function of current V(I) or a resistance as a function of current R(I) such that either V = R(I) * I (average resistance) or V = integral_0^I r(I') dI' (incremental resistance). In any case, it's not stateful, as soon as the current/voltage decreases, resistance goes back up, it's only absorbing the surge. It takes ~ms of fault current to open a breaker; the ~µs surge has no effect.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you again